# ¿Por qué cuando tengo dos spinners dentro del ciclo de vida de Android (onCreate) solo se muestra un Spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-spinner

Me encuentro realizando una aplicación bancaria. Esta aplicación consta de dos `Spinners`.

Estos realizan la siguiente función:

- Debe mostrar las formas de pago correspondientes (Pagar todo, Pagar en cuotas).
- Debe mostrar la cantidad de cuotas para realizar el pago en cuotas (1 y 2).

Mi duda es la siguiente, cada vez que realizo la programación dentro de `onCreate()` solo muestra un `Spinner`.
Estuve consultando el API y utilicé el método setOnItemSelectedListener (si pudieran explicarme mejor, lo agradecería bastante). Al utilizar dicho método apareció como en la imagen adjunta.

PD: Me encuentro programando en Java, NO KOTLIN.

Adjunto código:

[image: Imagen que visualiza el problema de los Spinners]

```
  package com.example.ev02mhariapaz_ramos;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.lang.reflect.Array;

    public class Deudas_act extends AppCompatActivity {

        private EditText ed1;
        private EditText ed2;
        private Spinner spinPagos;
        private Spinner spinCuotas;
        private TextView txt;
        private Button calcular;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_deudas_act);

            ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);
            ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed2);
            spinPagos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinPagos);
            spinCuotas = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinPagos);
            txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlgo);
            calcular = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalcular);
            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            String[] valor = b.getStringArray(("tipoPago"));
            String[] valor1 = b.getStringArray(("cantidadCuotas"));
            //ArrayAdapter adapt = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,valor);
            //spinPagos.setAdapter(adapt);
            ArrayAdapter adapt1 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,valor1);
            spinCuotas.setAdapter(adapt1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas enlazando los tus variables spinner a un solo espiner.

```
spinPagos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinPagos);
spinCuotas = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinPagos);/*cambia el nombre del id del segundo spinner */
```

Comment: Gracias por eso, claramente fue capa ocho

Comment: Hola @MharíaPazRamosMeneses que es "capa ocho" :) ?